# Making http request in for loop fails in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

i am doing lots of web request with asynchronous call in for loop but 3 call success out of 10 call. when i made it synchronous its success rate is 100%. but i want to do it asynchronously.Please help me. sample code is following:

```
+(void)saveExpenceInBackground
{

NSArray *array = [Expense getSortedExpenseForUser:[CoreDataManager sharedManager].User ForContext:[CoreDataManager sharedManager].managedObjectContext];

for (Expense *expence in array) {

    NSDictionary *reqDict = [kzExpenceDataAndServiceHandler convertObjectToDictionary:expence];

    [ExpenceDataAndServiceHandler expenceSaveToServer:reqDict];

 }
}



  +(void) expenceSaveToServer:
           requestDict :(NSDictionary *)reqDict                
{
@try {

    NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:reqDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=%@&data=%@",[postDict valueForKey:@"method"], dataString];

    NSString *webMethod = [self httpMethodTypeForServiceType:method];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[UserPreference objectForKey:kzBaseURL] stringByAppendingString:relativePath]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:webMethod];
    // [r setAllHTTPHeaderFields:dictHeaders];
    [request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//[inputParameter.dict_postParameters objectForKey:WebserviceJSONDataPostDictKey]
    [request setTimeoutInterval:120];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError)
        {
            return;
        }

        NSDictionary *responseDict = [btcWebserviceHelper jsonValidationWithDictionary:data];


        if (responseDict != nil) {

             NSMutableDictionary *dic = [responseDict mutableCopy];
            [dic setObject:[reqDict valueForKey:@"expence_id"] forKey:@"expence_id"];

           }

    }];


}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception %@",exception);
}
@finally {

}


}

 +(NSDictionary *)convertObjectToDictionary:(Expense *)expence
{

NSDictionary *requestDict = [@{@"receipt_key":expence.receipt_key,
                               @"store_name": expence.store_name,
                               @"amount": expence.amount,
                               @"date_purchase": expence.date_purchase,
                               @"is_processed":expence.is_processed?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"item_name":expence.item_name ,
                               @"user_folder": expence.user_folder ,
                               @"folder_name": expence.folder_name,
                               @"category_id": expence.category_id,
                               @"is_deleted": expence.is_deleted?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"is_approved": expence.is_approved?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"active_vat_percentage":![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.active_vat_percentage] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.active_vat_percentage:@"" ,
                               @"vat_qualified": expence.vat_qualified?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"vat_percentage": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.vat_percentage] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.vat_percentage:@"",
                               @"vat_amount": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.vat_amount] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.vat_amount:@"",
                               @"net_expense": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.net_expense] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.net_expense:@"",
                               @"is_fuel": expence.is_fuel?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"fuel_type": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.fuel_type] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.fuel_type:@"",
                               @"fuel_quantity": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.fuel_quantity] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.fuel_quantity:@"",
                               @"fuel_amount": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.fuel_amount] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.fuel_amount:@"",
                               @"fuel_rate": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.fuel_rate] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.fuel_rate:@"",
                               @"bank_account_id": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.bank_account_id] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.bank_account_id:@"",
                               @"is_paid": expence.is_paid?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"project_id": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.project_id] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.project_id:@"",
                               @"description": @"",
                               @"payment_method": ![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",expence.payment_method] isEqual: @"NaN"]?expence.payment_method:@"",
                               @"currency_id": expence.currency_id,
                               @"image_name": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%@",expence.receipt_key],
                               @"receipt_format": expence.receipt_format?expence.receipt_format:@"",
                               @"image_original": expence.image?expence.image:@"",
                               @"is_synced": expence.is_synced?[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                               @"expence_id":expence.expence_id?expence.expence_id:@"0",
                               @"receipt_uid":expence.receipt_uid?expence.receipt_uid:@"",
                               @"image_name":expence.image_name?expence.image_name:@""

                               } mutableCopy];


return  requestDict;
 }
```

Comment: You have to debug it and see what is failing; i.e. what is `nil` or what is returning an error.  For starters, you aren't reporting `connectionError` or JSON decoding errors.

Comment: yeah, I have debug it. I am using iOS7 in iphone 4. It is success in 5 and 5s with iOS8.4. but fail most of time in my device i.e. iphone4.

Comment: In what way does it fail?  You need to find out if you want to solve it.  I doubt anyone else can help without guessing.

Comment: I am calling request in loop. So i just want to know this approach it correct or not? also i have providing you my input dictionary parameters. The never be null.